# Why does apt-get update fail with 404 errors?

Tags: apt, ppa

I have a problem with my newly installed 12.10 86_64  Desktop.

This error pops up on console when I try to update apt-get or try to install packages and nodejs just don't work and there is no error on console.

```
Ignoring file 'eugenesan-java-quantal.list.save' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

this error started after my update on apt-get

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I'm a newbie on ubuntu.

this is the log file : (in Turkish 'Yoksay' = Ignored, 'Bağlandı' = Connected,  'getirilmesi başarısız oldu' = failed to get )

```
attila@Lupuseum:~$ sudo apt-get update
    Yoksay http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease
    Yoksay http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease                              
    Yoksay http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease                              
    Bağlandı http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release.gpg               
    Bağlandı http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg                          
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease                
    Yoksay http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease                    
    Bağlandı http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security Release         
    Bağlandı http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal Release                              
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease                  
    Bağlandı http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg                          
    Bağlandı http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Sources    
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports InRelease      
    Bağlandı http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources               
    Yoksay http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release.gpg                  
    Bağlandı http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Sources
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg            
    Bağlandı http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main amd64 Packages        
    Bağlandı http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release                    
    Bağlandı http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Sources          
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg              
    Bağlandı http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages                   
    Yoksay http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release                                
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg            
    Bağlandı http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources                         
    Bağlandı http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Sources
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release                          
    Bağlandı http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main amd64 Packages                  
    Bağlandı http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main amd64 Packages       
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release                  
    Bağlandı http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages                   
    Bağlandı http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted amd64 Packages 
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release      
    Bağlandı http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe amd64 Packages   
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Sources                     
    Bağlandı http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Sources     
    Bağlandı http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main i386 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Sources       
    Bağlandı http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted i386 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Sources     
    Bağlandı http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe i386 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main amd64 Packages    
    Bağlandı http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted amd64 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe amd64 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse amd64 Packages
    Bağlandı http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-en
    Yoksay http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-tr_CY       
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main i386 Packages     
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted i386 Packages
    Yoksay http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-tr          
    Bağlandı http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-en
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe i386 Packages           
    Yoksay http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en                    
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse i386 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-tr    
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-en
    Bağlandı http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-en
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-tr
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-en
    Bağlandı http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-en
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-tr
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-en
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-tr
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-en
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Sources
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Sources
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Sources
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Sources
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main amd64 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main i386 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe i386 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
    Yoksay http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-tr_CY
    Yoksay http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-tr
    Yoksay http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-en
    Hata http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources                   
      404  Not Found
    Hata http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main amd64 Packages            
      404  Not Found
    Hata http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages
      404  Not Found
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-en
    Yoksay http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-tr_CY
    Yoksay http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-tr_CY
    Yoksay http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-tr
    Yoksay http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Translation-tr
    Yoksay http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Translation-en
    Yoksay http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-tr_CY
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-en
    Yoksay http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/multiverse Translation-tr
    Yoksay http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-tr_CY
    Yoksay http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/restricted Translation-tr
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-en
    Yoksay http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-tr_CY
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Sources
    Yoksay http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/universe Translation-tr
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Sources
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Sources
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Sources
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main amd64 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted amd64 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe amd64 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main i386 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted i386 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe i386 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-en
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-en
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-en
    Bağlandı http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-en
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/main Translation-tr_CY
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/multiverse Translation-tr_CY
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/restricted Translation-tr_CY
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal/universe Translation-tr_CY
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-tr_CY
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/main Translation-tr
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-tr_CY
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/multiverse Translation-tr
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-tr_CY
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/restricted Translation-tr
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-tr_CY
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates/universe Translation-tr
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-tr_CY
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/main Translation-tr
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-tr_CY
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/multiverse Translation-tr
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-tr_CY
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/restricted Translation-tr
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-tr_CY
    Yoksay http://cy.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports/universe Translation-tr
    N: Ignoring file 'eugenesan-java-quantal.list.save' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
    W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/richarvey/nodejs/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources 404  Not Found getirilmesi başarısız oldu
    W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/richarvey/nodejs/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404  Not Found getirilmesi başarısız oldu
    W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/richarvey/nodejs/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found getirilmesi başarısız oldu
    E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not this:

```
Ignoring file 'eugenesan-java-quantal.list.save' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

It's OK to have ".save" files: they are just backup copies. Your problem is this:

```
[...]
Hata http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources                   
  404  Not Found
Hata http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main amd64 Packages            
  404  Not Found
Hata http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
[...]
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/richarvey/nodejs/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources 404  Not Found getirilmesi başarısız oldu
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/richarvey/nodejs/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404  Not Found getirilmesi başarısız oldu
W: http://ppa.launchpad.net/richarvey/nodejs/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages 404  Not Found getirilmesi başarısız oldu
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

In fact, if you look at the [PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~richarvey/+archive/nodejs) you'll see that packages are built just for Precise, not for Quantal.

You should either:

1. find an another PPA which builds NodeJS packages for Quantal; or
2. edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/richarvey-nodejs-precise.list` and replace "quantal" with "precise".

Comment: option two while valid will have long term issues. As Quantal and Precise get further apart, dependencies will become a problem.

Comment: Both Precise and Quantal have been released; no relevant changes will ever be introduced. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates for more information.

Comment: thanx for the answer. 2. way is worked